# where is memory going in In-Memory OLTP?

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-database

I have only memory optimized table in my database. When I am running below query, I am getting pages_mb for that DB as 710 MB.

```
SELECT type  
 , name  
 , memory_node_id  
 , pages_kb/1024 AS pages_MB   
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks WHERE type LIKE '%xtp%'
```

But when I run below query, I am getting mem_alloc_total_mb for that table as 2 and others as 0.

```
   SELECT
   object_name(object_id) AS table_name,
   memory_allocated_for_indexes_kb / 1024 as mem_alloc_index_mb,
   memory_allocated_for_table_kb / 1024 as mem_alloc_table_mb,
   memory_used_by_indexes_kb / 1024 as mem_used_index_mb,
   memory_used_by_table_kb / 1024 as mem_used_table_mb,
   (memory_allocated_for_table_kb + memory_allocated_for_indexes_kb) / 1024 as mem_alloc_total_mb,
   (memory_used_by_table_kb + memory_used_by_indexes_kb) /1024 as mem_used_total_mb
   FROM sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats
   where object_id = object_id('<table_name>');
   go
```

Data from both the above queries are contradicting each other. Am I missing anything?

*NOTE: Durability setting for the memory optimized tabe is "SCHEMA_AND_DATA".*

Answer (score 1):

Memory for In-Memory OLTP is under the sp_configure setting for max memory, but is not part of the buffer pool. Not sure if that helps or not. You could have a lot of stale rows that are waiting until there is memory pressure in order to be "garbage collected". I wrote a script that's part of Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit that might be of some help to you, located here:

https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_BlitzInMemoryOLTP.sql